# Swiper slide to index

Tags: swiper.js

I have a svg-map with a few countries. Each country has a different ID.
If I click on a country, my swiper should move to the slide with the matching active index.

Example:
`<a href="#BRD0" class="brd active" data-id="0" target="_self"title="index1">`

my script:
`$('.brd.active').on('click', function() { var dataID  =   jQuery(this).attr('data-id'); brdswiper.slideTo(dataID);`

This works if I initially click on the first data-id item, but if I click on another id first, my swiper moves to the wrong id.